# my auto form wont output the correct value

Tags: javascript, html

im trying to build an auto estimator form but when i do width 30ft and length 16ft i get 000000000003 on mytotal some bits are missing but all the ifs yet it still outputs different

i have tryed everything and i cant get it to work could someone help please
https://codepen.io/callum-edwards/pen/oNvBWxo

$('#plaster').html( 49.84 + price );

```js
$(function(){
$(function () {
    var fields = $('select[name=bead],select[name=cpu],select[name=GPU]').change(calculate);

    function calculate() {
        var price = 0;
        fields.each(function () {
            price += +$(this).val();
        })
        $('#price').html(price.toFixed(2));
      if (price >= 10) {
  $('#test').html( "You would need 1 bags of plaster Costing £6.23" );
         document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute('value','6.23');
          $('#plaster').html( price + 6.23 );

}
if (price == 20) {
  $('#test').html( "You  would need 1 bags of plaster Costing £66.23" );
            document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute('value','6.23');

    $('#plaster').html( price + 6.23 );

}
if (price == 30) {
  $('#test').html( "You would need 1 bags of plaster Costing £6.23" );
           document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute('value','6.23');

     $('#plaster').html( price + 6.23 );

}

if (price >= 40) {
  $('#test').html( "You would need 2 bags of plaster Costing £1f2.46" );
           document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute('value','12.46');

     $('#plaster').html( price + 12.46 );

}

if (price >= 50) {
  $('#test').html( "You would need 2 bags of plaster Costing £12.46" );           document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute('value','12.46');

       $('#plaster').html( price + 12.46 );

}
if (price >= 60) {
  $('#test').html( "You would need 2 bags of plaster Costing £12.46" );           document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute('value','12.46');

     $('#plaster').html( price + 12.46 );

}
if (price >= 70) {
  $('#test').html( "You would need 3 bags of plaster Costing £18.69" );           document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute('value','18.69');

     $('#plaster').html( price + 18.69 );
}
if (price >= 80) {
  $('#test').html( "You would need 3 bags of plaster Costing £18.69" );
  document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute('value','18.69');
     $('#plaster').html( price + 18.69 );
}
if (price >= 90) {
  $('#test').html( "You would need 3 bags of plaster Costing £18.69" );
  document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute('value','18.69');
     $('#plaster').html( price + 18.69 );

}
if (price >= 100) {
  $('#test').html( "You would need 4 bags of plaster costing £24.92" );
  document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute('value','24.92');
     $('#plaster').html( price + 24.92 );

}
if (price >= 110) {
  $('#test').html( "You would need 4 bags of plaster costing £24.92" );  document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute('value','24.92');

     $('#plaster').html( price + 24.92 );

}
if (price >= 120) {
  $('#test').html( "You would need 4 bags of plaster costing £24.92" );  document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute('value','24.92');

     $('#plaster').html( price + 24.92 );

}
if (price >= 130) {
  $('#test').html( "You would need 5 bags of plaster costing £31.15" );  document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute('value','31.15');

     $('#plaster').html( price + 31.15 );
}
if (price >= 140) {
  $('#test').html( "You would need 5 bags of plaster costing £31.15" );
  document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute('value','31.15');
     $('#plaster').html( price + 31.15 );
}
if (price >= 150) {
  $('#test').html( "You would need 5 bags of plaster costing £31.15" );
  document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute('value','31.15');
  $('#plaster').html( price + 31.15 );
}
if (price >= 160) {
  $('#test').html( "You would need 6 bags of plaster costing £37.38" );
  document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute('value','37.38');
  $('#plaster').html( price + 37.38 );

}
if (price >= 170) {
  $('#test').html( "You would need 6 bags of plaster costing £37.38" );
  document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute('value','37.38');
  $('#plaster').html( price + 37.38 );

}
if (price >= 180) {
  $('#test').html( "You would need 6 bags of plaster costing £37.38" );
  document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute('value','37.38');
  $('#plaster').html( price + 37.38 );
}

if (price >= 190) {
  $('#test').html( "You would need 7 bags of plaster costing £43.61" );
  document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute('value','43.61');
  $('#plaster').html( price + 43.61 );

}

if (price >= 200) {
  $('#test').html( "You would need 7 bags of plaster costing £43.61" );
    document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute('value','43.61');
  $('#plaster').html( price + 43.61 );

}
if (price >= 210) {
  $('#test').html( "You would need 7 bags of plaster costing £43.61" );
    document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute('value','43.61');
  $('#plaster').html( price + 43.61 );

}
if (price >= 220) {
  $('#test').html( "You would need 7 bags of plaster costing £43.61" );
    document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute('value','49.84');
  $('#plaster').html( 49.84 + price );

}
if (price >= 230) {


  $('#plaster').html( price + 49.84 );

}
if (price >= 240) {
  $('#test').html( "You would need 8 bags of plaster costing £49.84" ); document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute('value','49.84');
  $('#plaster').html( price + 49.84 );

}
if (price >= 250) {
  $('#test').html( "You would need 9 bags of plaster costing £57.06" ); document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute('value','57.06');
  $('#plaster').html( price + 57.06 );

}
if (price >= 260) {
  $('#test').html( "You would need 9 bags of plaster costing £57.06" );
  document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute('value','57.06');
  $('#plaster').html( price + 57.06 );

}
if (price >= 270) {
  $('#test').html( "You would need 9 bags of plaster costing £57.06" );
  document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute('value','57.06');
  $('#plaster').html( price + 57.06 );

}
if (price >= 280) {
  $('#test').html( "You would need 10 bags of plaster costing £62.30" );
  document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute('value','62.30');
  $('#plaster').html( price + 62.30 );

}
if (price >= 290) {
  $('#test').html( "You would need 10 bags of plaster costing £62.30" );  document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute('value','62.30');
  $('#plaster').html( price + 62.30 );


}
if (price >= 300) {
  $('#test').html( "You would  need 10 bags of plaster costing £62.30" );  document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute('value','62.30');
  $('#plaster').html( price + 62.30 );
}

      }   

})

    });

//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
        'position': 'absolute'
      });
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

    //de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
            left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
    return false;

})
```

$('#plaster').html( price + 49.84 );

it says 000000000003 yet the others down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your example provides the usage of two decimal numbers, I will suggest you a quick fix.

At the bottom of your `calculate()` function (after the last `if` conditional), add the following lines to parse the content:

```
let p = $("#plaster")
p.html( Math.round(+p.html() * 1000) / 1000 )
```

This is a trick to reduce the whole float value to only two decimal values (if it is necessary). Doing this, your code would parse the number to two decimal numbers every time the function is called.

See it working:

```js
$(function() {
  $(function() {
    var fields = $(
      "select[name=bead],select[name=cpu],select[name=GPU]"
    ).change(calculate);

    function calculate() {
      var price = 0;
      fields.each(function() {
        price += +$(this).val();
      });
      $("#price").html(price.toFixed(2));
      if (price >= 10) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 1 bags of plaster Costing £6.23");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "6.23");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 6.23 );
      }
      if (price == 20) {
        $("#test").html("You  would need 1 bags of plaster Costing £66.23");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "6.23");

        $("#plaster").html(price + 6.23);
      }
      if (price == 30) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 1 bags of plaster Costing £6.23");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "6.23");

        $("#plaster").html( ((price + 6.23) * 100) / 100 );
      }

      if (price >= 40) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 2 bags of plaster Costing £1f2.46");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "12.46");

        $("#plaster").html(price + 12.46);
      }

      if (price >= 50) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 2 bags of plaster Costing £12.46");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "12.46");

        $("#plaster").html(price + 12.46);
      }
      if (price >= 60) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 2 bags of plaster Costing £12.46");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "12.46");

        $("#plaster").html(price + 12.46);
      }
      if (price >= 70) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 3 bags of plaster Costing £18.69");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "18.69");

        $("#plaster").html(price + 18.69);
      }
      if (price >= 80) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 3 bags of plaster Costing £18.69");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "18.69");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 18.69);
      }
      if (price >= 90) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 3 bags of plaster Costing £18.69");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "18.69");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 18.69);
      }
      if (price >= 100) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 4 bags of plaster costing £24.92");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "24.92");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 24.92);
      }
      if (price >= 110) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 4 bags of plaster costing £24.92");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "24.92");

        $("#plaster").html(price + 24.92);
      }
      if (price >= 120) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 4 bags of plaster costing £24.92");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "24.92");

        $("#plaster").html(price + 24.92);
      }
      if (price >= 130) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 5 bags of plaster costing £31.15");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "31.15");

        $("#plaster").html(price + 31.15);
      }
      if (price >= 140) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 5 bags of plaster costing £31.15");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "31.15");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 31.15);
      }
      if (price >= 150) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 5 bags of plaster costing £31.15");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "31.15");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 31.15);
      }
      if (price >= 160) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 6 bags of plaster costing £37.38");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "37.38");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 37.38);
      }
      if (price >= 170) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 6 bags of plaster costing £37.38");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "37.38");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 37.38);
      }
      if (price >= 180) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 6 bags of plaster costing £37.38");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "37.38");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 37.38);
      }

      if (price >= 190) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 7 bags of plaster costing £43.61");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "43.61");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 43.61);
      }

      if (price >= 200) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 7 bags of plaster costing £43.61");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "43.61");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 43.61);
      }
      if (price >= 210) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 7 bags of plaster costing £43.61");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "43.61");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 43.61);
      }
      if (price >= 220) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 7 bags of plaster costing £43.61");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "49.84");
        $("#plaster").html(49.84 + price);
      }
      if (price >= 230) {
        $("#plaster").html(price + 49.84);
      }
      if (price >= 240) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 8 bags of plaster costing £49.84");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "49.84");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 49.84);
      }
      if (price >= 250) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 9 bags of plaster costing £57.06");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "57.06");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 57.06);
      }
      if (price >= 260) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 9 bags of plaster costing £57.06");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "57.06");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 57.06);
      }
      if (price >= 270) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 9 bags of plaster costing £57.06");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "57.06");
        $("#plaster").html( ((price + 57.06) * 100) / 100);
      }
      if (price >= 280) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 10 bags of plaster costing £62.30");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "62.30");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 62.3);
      }
      if (price >= 290) {
        $("#test").html("You would need 10 bags of plaster costing £62.30");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "62.30");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 62.3);
      }
      if (price >= 300) {
        $("#test").html("You would  need 10 bags of plaster costing £62.30");
        document.getElementById("ouch").setAttribute("value", "62.30");
        $("#plaster").html(price + 62.3);
      }
      let p = $("#plaster")
      p.html( Math.round(+p.html() * 1000)/1000 )
    }
  });
});

//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function() {
  if (animating) return false;
  animating = true;

  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  next_fs = $(this)
    .parent()
    .next();

  //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
  $("#progressbar li")
    .eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs))
    .addClass("active");

  //show the next fieldset
  next_fs.show();
  //hide the current fieldset with style
  current_fs.animate(
    { opacity: 0 },
    {
      step: function(now, mx) {
        //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
        //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
        scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
        //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
        left = now * 50 + "%";
        //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
        opacity = 1 - now;
        current_fs.css({
          transform: "scale(" + scale + ")",
          position: "absolute"
        });
        next_fs.css({ left: left, opacity: opacity });
      },
      duration: 800,
      complete: function() {
        current_fs.hide();
        animating = false;
      },
      //this comes from the custom easing plugin
      easing: "easeInOutBack"
    }
  );
});

$(".previous").click(function() {
  if (animating) return false;
  animating = true;

  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  previous_fs = $(this)
    .parent()
    .prev();

  //de-activate current step on progressbar
  $("#progressbar li")
    .eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs))
    .removeClass("active");

  //show the previous fieldset
  previous_fs.show();
  //hide the current fieldset with style
  current_fs.animate(
    { opacity: 0 },
    {
      step: function(now, mx) {
        //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
        //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
        scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
        //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
        left = (1 - now) * 50 + "%";
        //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
        opacity = 1 - now;
        current_fs.css({ left: left });
        previous_fs.css({
          transform: "scale(" + scale + ")",
          opacity: opacity
        });
      },
      duration: 800,
      complete: function() {
        current_fs.hide();
        animating = false;
      },
      //this comes from the custom easing plugin
      easing: "easeInOutBack"
    }
  );
});

$(".submit").click(function() {
  return false;
});
```

```css
/*custom font*/
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

html {
 height: 100%;
 /*Image only BG fallback*/
 
 /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
 background: 
  linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.6), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.6));
}

body {
 font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
}
/*form styles*/
#msform {
 width: 400px;
 margin: 50px auto;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}
#msform fieldset {
 background: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 padding: 20px 30px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 10%;
 
 /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
 position: relative;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
 display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
#msform select, #msform input, #msform textarea {
 padding: 15px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: montserrat;
 color: #2C3E50;
 font-size: 13px;
}
/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
 width: 100px;
 background: #27AE60;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 10px 5px;
 margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
/*headings*/
.fs-title {
 font-size: 15px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #2C3E50;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-subtitle {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #666;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 overflow: hidden;
 /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
 counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
 list-style-type: none;
 color: white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 9px;
 width: 33.33%;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
 content: counter(step);
 counter-increment: step;
 width: 20px;
 line-height: 20px;
 display: block;
 font-size: 10px;
 color: #333;
 background: white;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
 content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 2px;
 background: white;
 position: absolute;
 left: -50%;
 top: 9px;
 z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
 /*connector not needed before the first step*/
 content: none; 
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
 background: #27AE60;
 color: white;
}
#msform .ms-field-title {
    color: #5a5a5a;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>

<!-- multistep form -->
<form id="msform">
  <!-- progressbar -->
  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
    <li>Social Profiles</li>
    <li>Personal Details</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- fieldsets -->
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Crreate your account</h2>
    Labour:<h3 class="fs-subtitle">£<u name="price" id="price"></u></h3><u name="plaster" id="plaster"></u><input hidden type="text" id="ouch" />
    <select name="cpu" id="CPU">
            <option value="0" selected>Width</option>
            <option value="10">2ft</option>
            <option value="20">4ft</option>
            <option value="30">6ft</option>
            <option value="40">8ft</option>
            <option value="50">10ft</option>
            <option value="60">12ft</option>
            <option value="70">14ft</option>
            <option value="80">16ft</option>
            <option value="90">18ft</option>
            <option value="100">20ft</option>
            <option value="110">22ft</option>
            <option value="120">24ft</option>
            <option value="130">26ft</option>
            <option value="140">28ft</option>
            <option value="150">30ft</option>
        </select></span>
           <select name="GPU" id="GPU">
                        <option value="0" selected>Length</option>
            <option value="10">2ft</option>
            <option value="20">4ft</option>
            <option value="30">6ft</option>
            <option value="40">8ft</option>
            <option value="50">10ft</option>
            <option value="60">12ft</option>
            <option value="70">14ft</option>
            <option value="80">16ft</option>
            <option value="90">18ft</option>
            <option value="100">20ft</option>
            <option value="110">22ft</option>
            <option value="120">24ft</option>
            <option value="130">26ft</option>
            <option value="140">28ft</option>
            <option value="150">30ft</option>
        </select>
     <select value="0" name="bead" id="bead">
                        <option value="0" selected>External Corners</option>
            <option value="2.25">1</option>
            <option value="11.11">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
                                                                    <span style="text-align:left;" id="test" class="ms-field-title"><sup>*</sup></span>
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
    <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
    <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
    <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
    <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: you super star thank you. its been racking my brain for days

Comment: @callum Always glad to help! Welcome to Stackoverflow:) I would suggest you to take a moment to read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Happy coding!

Comment: when i change select external corner it says zero and cant get it to sero when i de select could you help please https://codepen.io/callum-edwards/pen/oNvBWxo

Comment: @callum if your issue is longer, I'd suggest to ask a different question for this issue. And I'll gladly help once again:)

Comment: ive added anothher question